# Set value of input fields to 0 with wordpress function

Tags: javascript, input, hook-woocommerce

I have am using wordpress and woocommerce to for a website.

I have a product that creates input fields to add quanitity of product to the carts.  Right now when someone adds to their cart, that quanitity doesn't get reset.  I'd like to get it reset but I think it needs JS and I'm not sure how to use it.

Here's what I know:

the input fields are rendered like this:

```
<input type="number" id="quantity_5dc486fedb5ff" class="input-text qty text" step="1" min="0" max="9999" name="quantity[1293]" value="0" title="Qty" size="4" inputmode="numeric">
```

Woocommerce has a hook that fires after someone adds something to their cart:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'clear_bundle_values' );

function clear_bundle_values(){
        //not sure what to put here
}
```

So I need to write a function that will set the `.quantity input` to `0` when this code is called.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the quantity field always has the same ID, you can use the following vanilla JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('quantity_5dc486fedb5ff').value = '0';
```

Else, you can target it via its class name 'qty' (note the plural Element**s**):

```
document.getElementsByClassName('qty')[0].value = '0';
```

If you've got access to jQuery, you can use a regex to target the input field even if the ID changes, as long as it begins with 'quantity_':

```
$("input[id^='quantity_']").val('0');
```

**UPDATE:** In context, this would be:

```
    function clear_bundle_values(){
    ?>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('quantity_5dc486fedb5ff').value = '0';
    </script>
    <?php
    }
```

Comment: How do I put that into my php function above?

Comment: Updated with code in context.  You can just close the PHP tags, put in your JavaScript and then open them again.  If this doesn't work, you'll need to add the JS to an external file and enqueue it the 'proper' way using wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script.

Comment: i'll try!  Thanks!